# Windows Azure: update git when website changes?

Tags: git, azure

Is it possible to configure Windows Azure to periodically update git deployment repository so that it contains changes done to website outside of git? For example when I do Wordpress update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can do it, but it might be really messy.

You can setup a cron job/scheduled job that pushes changes to git. One major problem however is that Git can't always auto-merge conflicts.

You can always look into backing up the machine automatically with blob storage. At my current place we have a cron job on Linux machines and a scheduled job on Windows to backup data and ship it off to blob storage.